# symfony2 forms custom fields

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine

So, I have a form for editing blog articles.

Among other things I need to be able to edit article **tags**. They are stored as ArrayCollection inside my Blog entity. (ManyToMany cascade: persist,remove)

Now, Simfony handles this type of data with `<select>` tag and it works just fine for selecting, but I want to be able to remove and add tags too.

This is also possible and is very well explained in this Cookbook article: [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)

However, result of this tutorial is still not very elegant and I would love to have input box similar to StackOverflow tag box.

Since there are many already done solutions under free licences I decided to just use one of them, for example [jQuery Tags Input](http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/).

Basically, all I need to do is run $('#tags_input_box').tagsInput() and it transforms it into SO-like tag box.

**Now, I'm searching for the easiest way to bind some custom made input to my form and submit it back together with the rest of 'genuine' fields in a shape that will be understood by Symfony2**.

Could anyone refer me to some document or give me some starting info where I should begin my research on this matter ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that plugin sends it in as a comma-separated string value.

Probably the easiest way would be to simply treat it as a single input in your form, and then split it up when you process the form.

```
// Entity to hold it in string form.
namespace Some\Entity;

class TagStringEntity {
    protected $tagString;

    // getTagString and setTagString
}

// Custom form type.
// Use this AbstractType in your form.
namespace Some\Form;

Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;

class TagType extends AbstractType {
     public buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) {
         $builder->add('tagString'); // will default to text field.
     }
}

// In Controller
public function displayFormAction() {
    // Join the tags into a single string.
    $tagString = implode(',', $article->getTags()); // assuming it returns an array of strings.

    $tagStringType = new TagStringType();
    $tagStringType->setTagString($tagString);

    // build form, etc...
}

public function checkFormAction() {
    // ...
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // Get the tag string, split it, and manually create your separated tag objects to store.
    }
}
```

That's probably the cleanest and simplest way to do it using that jQuery plugin. Takes a bit of working around since you are turning multiple items into many and vice versa, but not too bad.

Comment: To make it more cleaner you can use [DataTransformers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html). Same idea except for splitting/joining is hidden from a controller

Comment: Thanks guys,you got me on the right track! I made it work and will post full code here tomorrow since I can't find anything like this on web. I would also appreciate if you would comment and tell me if I'm mistaken somewhere since my code works, but it does feel a bit *hackish*

@meze DataTransformers are amazing, I was afraid to open that section of Symfony2 cookbook but once I did I realized they weren't hard to understand concept at all! Thanks a lot for that info!

Comment: Thanks meze, I didn't know about the DataTransformers feature either. Learn something new every day. ;)